# issues when change word table column width and insert a picture into word from excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to use vba to combine the text, table and picture into a word file from excel file. The below code works most of time. However, error 462 appears occasionally.

I searched around. Some comments said it appears because the unqualified references exist. However, I don't know what and where the unqualified reference is. A weird thing: usually the first running is ok. After that, this error usually appears in the even times, only. I am sure I closed the word file every time, no matter whether the code executes successfully or not.

Here is the code. I put the comment to indicate the line where the error occurs.

```
Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object

Set WordApp = New Word.Application

With WordApp
    .Visible = True

    Set WordDoc = .Documents.Add
    .ActiveDocument.Select
    With .Selection
    'narrative
    Sheet3.Range("G2").Copy
    .PasteExcelTable False, False, False

    'IO
    Sheet2.Range("A1","B11").Copy
    .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    WordDoc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Width = InchesToPoints(1.5) 'Error 462 appears periodically on this line
    WordDoc.Tables(1).Columns(2).Width = InchesToPoints(4.5)
    WordDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Height = 20

    'HMI
    Sheet9.Range("A4").Copy
    .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    Sheet9.Shapes("Group_Htr").Copy
    .PasteSpecial   
    .ShapeRange(1).WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapInline
    .EndKey unit:=wdStory
    'P&ID
    .TypeParagraph
    .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
        With .PageSetup
            .LineNumbering.Active = False
            .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
            .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
            .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
            .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
            .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
            .Gutter = InchesToPoints(0)
            .HeaderDistance = InchesToPoints(0.5)
            .FooterDistance = InchesToPoints(0.5)
            .PageWidth = InchesToPoints(11)
            .PageHeight = InchesToPoints(17)
            .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
            .OtherPagesTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
            .SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
            .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
            .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
            .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
            .SuppressEndnotes = False
            .MirrorMargins = False
            .TwoPagesOnOne = False
            .BookFoldPrinting = False
            .BookFoldRevPrinting = False
            .BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
            .GutterPos = wdGutterPosLeft
            If .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait Then
                .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
            End If
        End With
    Sheet10.Range("A4").Copy
    .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    Sheet10.Shapes("Group_Htr").Copy
    .PasteSpecial                   'Error 4198 appears occasionally on this line
    End With
    .Activate

End With
```

Comment: When you have errors it's important to also give the *text*, not just the number. No one has memorized the text for thousands of possible error numbers...

Comment: You should have only **one** question / Question - site rules. There are two reasons for this: 1) This is a Q&A site, not a forum and 2) No single person may know all the answers to all the questions. So you may get no answes, or only partial answers... and multiple partial answers is not good for the Q&A concept. I've edited your question to leave only one question - the first. Implement the answer I'll write, then see if that helps solve any of the other problems. If not, post new questions for each problem.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Also, thank you for correcting my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get the error is because `InchesToPoints` is not part of Excel, which is where the code is running. This method is specific to Word, so it requires a reference to the Word.Application. Put a `.` in front of each occurrence so that it picks up `WordApp` from the `With`:

```
WordDoc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Width = .InchesToPoints(1.5)
```

Comment: I put a `WordApp.` in front of `.InchesToPints()` and it works well. Looks like putting a `.` will let the code pick up `.Selection` or `.PageSetup`, not `WordApp`, from the `with`. Thank you, Cindy.

Comment: @PeterLau Ah, yes, because it's within a second `With` - I missed that. Glad you figured it out!